# expected 0-1 arguments but got 5 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In this part code --> expected 0-1 arguments but got 5.
Can you suggest me any solution?

```
  Register() {
        let newUser = new User(this.registerForm.value,
        newUser.city =this.cityid,
        newUser.regionId = this.regionid,
        newUser.country_id = this.countryid,
        newUser.roleId = this.roleid,
        );
          this.ws.createUser(newUser).subscribe(
        );
      }


    export class User {  
      password: string;
      roleId: string;
      firstName: string;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you added a constructor with the fields in `User`?

Comment: Yes! Like this:   constructor(obj?: any) {
    if (obj) {.......}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor setting the values to the class variables.

```
class User {
  //declarations
  constructor(value, city, regionId, countryId, roleid) {
    this.value = value;
    this.city = city;
    this.regionId = regionId;
    this.countryId = countryId;
    this.roleId = roleId;
  }
  //...
}
```

You are providing 5 arguments to the constructor, so it needs to have 5 values there.

If you actually want to pass an object, then pass an object as argument:

```
let newUser = new User(this.registerForm.value);
//rest of the code
```

Comment: Yes, I understand you. Your code like good, but I want ID of value, ex, 1.2.3 etc, not name of value. For this reason I want to use   newUser.city =this.cityid,
        newUser.regionId = this.regionid,
        newUser.country_id = this.countryid,
        newUser.roleId = this.roleid

Comment: Your issue is that you are passing 5 arguments to a constructor that accepts an optional object. I'm not sure I understand what you want

Comment: Thank you, I fix it.Like this:   let newUser =  this.registerForm.value
    newUser.city = this.cityid;
    newUser.region_id = this.regionid;
    newUser.country_id = this.countryid;
    newUser.id = this.roleid;
    let user = new User(newUser);